# Apple Rejects multiple times due to crash but not happening in Real Time devices and Simulator

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, apple-developer

We tried uploading our apps to apps store and initailly they rejected the app that the app is crashing on ipad with so and so version. We tested exactly with the same version of iPad via TestFlight and there is no crash is happening and we resubmitted the review and its rejected again.

Now they are telling the app is not working in iPhone 13 and we tested with the exact same device with the specified version and there is no crash. So we uploaded a recorded video and resubmitted the review.

Still they are rejecting the app stated that the app is crashing in iPad during login. Now we uploaded 3 different videos of iPhone 13, iPad and iPhone XR devices with different versions stated that we couldn't identify any crashes during login. But Still they rejected the app.

There is no crash report generated. But whatever they sent we tried to replicate its not happening. Kindly provide if there is an solution for this.

Comment: Apple won't approve a video.  You need to work out why it is crashing on their device.  They will typically provide a crash dump with your rejection. Test with no network. Test with a pure IPv6 network.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to Suggest 2 Points

1)First:-
Please test for :
different TimeZones
different DateFormats
different Orientations (If Supported)
no Internet Connectivity
idle ScreenTime
Low Internet Api Handling
and any Other Specific scenarios that are needed for your integrations.

2)Second:-

Before Submitting your next Build please add Firebase Crashlytics Tool for Crash report so that when such a situation arises you will have data and reporting on the occurred crashes.

Here You can Get info about the same: [Firebase CrashLytics Info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)